# Uploading a remote file url from Rails Console with Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, carrierwave

I just wanted to know how one would go about uploading a remote file url using Carrierwave in the Rails console.

I tried the following without any luck. I presume it's not processing the Uploader?

```
user = User.first
user.remote_avatar_url = "http://www.image.com/file.jpg"
user.save
```

Many thanks

Comment: This is the correct syntax. What does your development.log say?

Comment: that of course assumes the User `mounts_uploader :avatar`

Comment: Thanks for responding Jesse. I am user mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader. My logs don't actually show anything. I must be missing something. It works fine going through the browser.

Comment: Okay, it looks like it's working now. I had to run it within my Vagrant VM's SSH.

Answer (score 28):

Take a look at the '**Uploading files from a remote location**' section on this page https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave

CarrierWave should throw an error if the url of the location is invalid

```
2.1.3 :015 > image.remote_image_url = "http"
 => "http"
2.1.3 :016 > image.save!
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Image trying to download a file which is not served over HTTP
```

Or if it's an unknown host:

```
2.1.3 :017 > image.remote_image_url = "http://foobar"
=> "http://foobar"
2.1.3 :018 > image.save!
   (0.4ms)  BEGIN
   (0.4ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Image could not download file: getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Please also note that if you want to download remote images you should prefix the attribute with `remote_` and suffix it with `_url`, as shown in the example

Comment: I am facing issue that it's working fine when creating new entry and saving remote URL with `image.remote_image_url = "somevalidurl"` but when updating it's not updating new image.

Answer (score 7):

```
user = User.first
user.remote_avatar = File.open(FILE_LOCATION)
user.save
```

FILE_LOCATION can be

```
File.join(Rails.root, '/files/png-sample.png')
```

if file is found in a folder 'files' in rails project

Comment: the question is how can I upload a file from a REMOTE LOCATION (a remote URL). Not a file on my system.

Comment: if so then just use the method `user.remote_avatar_url = "www.example.com/image.jpg`, Carrierwave will simply download the file and add re-upload it on your application.

Answer (score 5):

I was facing the same problem. and the issue might be http is redirecting to https. So I replaced them using gsub as follows:

```
image.remote_image_url = remote_image_url.gsub('http://','https://')
image.save!
```

this should most probably solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Is work as:

```
url='http://host.domain/file.jpg'    
time=Time.now.to_i.to_s
myfile=IO.sysopen("tmp/"+time+"_img."+url.split(".").last,"wb+")
tmp_img=IO.new(myfile,"wb")
tmp_img.write open(URI.encode(url)).read

if File.exist?("tmp/"+time+"_img."+url.split(".").last)
  "tmp/"+time+"_img."+url.split(".").last
  image = ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile.new(:tempfile => tmp_img, :filename => File.basename(tmp_img))
else 
  image=nil
end
@your_model.image=image
@your_model.save
```

Answer (score -1):

I have had problems with remote_avatar_url not uploading the image or throwing any errors.  For me, as far as I can tell, it was because I set the following in my model.

```
attr_accessor :remote_avatar_url
```

Carrierwave covers this for you, and although I don't understand why, setting it yourself buggers things up.

Comment: If you do that it will, in essence, overwrite carrierwave's declaration of `remote_avatar_url`.