# Uploading pdf document with carrier wave from remote url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I m trying to generate some test data on the test environment, and have some random PDF urls that we can use for testing. My AR class looks like this :

```
class PDF::Template < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :document, PdfUploader
end
```

Using ruby code or code that I can run via rake task or via rails console? How can I upload something from random pdf url?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uploading a remote file url from Rails Console with Carrierwave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16918588/uploading-a-remote-file-url-from-rails-console-with-carrierwave)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Carrierwave wiki](http://Source:%20https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-Upload-remote-image-urls-to-your-seedfile):

> If you're looking to quickly generate some seed data for your application and don't want to upload images already stored in your
>   application you can easily upload remote images by using
>   `remote_[your_image_attribute_name]_url`
>
> ```
>     Galaxy.destroy_all
>     Galaxy.create!(name: 'Andromeda', remote_photo_url: 'http://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/1407/m31_bers_960.jpg', address: 'next to the Milky Way')
> ```

Comment: so it's `remote_document_url` ?